# Add Hover and click event to the dropdown button -Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have added hover and click events to open the dropdown content.

It is working as effect but with minor glitch

On hover, content is opening fine and on hover hiding.

On the first click it is opening fine but on second click it is not closing immediately and I need to exit the hover state to see the second click effect

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

 .openCont{
  display:block !important;
}

.closeCont{
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Mouse over me</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="dropdown">
  <button>Mouse over me</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
    console.log('toggle')
    $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").toggleClass('openCont');

});
```

Comment: Of course it does like that, as you still are `hover` which says it should be visible

Comment: Why both use `hover` and a `click`? ... I mean if the `click` should work properly the `hover` will not and vice versa

Comment: @LGSon, actually hover is just to see the content at glance but I have requirement to open it on click to make content visible and second click hide it

Comment: @LGSon I tried with .css , combining click and hover in same even as .on('hover click') but only one works correctly n other fails

Comment: Posted an answer for you, that actually will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do like this it will work, add a `mouseout` handler

```
$(".dropdown").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").removeClass('closeCont');
});
```

update your JS

```
$(this).find("div.dropdown-content").toggleClass('openCont closeCont');
if ($(this).is(":hover")) {
  $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").addClass('closeCont');
}
```

update your CSS by changing this rule

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content:not(.closeCont) {
    display: block;
}
```

swap order on these 2 rules so `openCont` is last (and remove `!important`)

```
.closeCont{
  display: none;
}
.openCont{
  display:block;
}
```

What make it work is after you clicked to hide it, it hides but as soon as you move mouse outside it also removes the `closeCont` which will make it work again when hovering

Stack snippet

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
    console.log('toggle')
    $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").toggleClass('openCont closeCont');
    if ($(this).is(":hover")) {
      $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").addClass('closeCont');
    }
});

$(".dropdown").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").removeClass('closeCont');
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content:not(.closeCont) {
    display: block;
}
.closeCont{
  display: none;
}
.openCont{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Mouse over me</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="dropdown">
  <button>Mouse over me</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @LGSon, but one issue is that to make second click work , I need too unhover and hover back and click..same issue which I am facing now :(

Comment: @divyareddy Updated with a fix

Answer (score 0):

It's not a glitch : You tell it that "when hovering show panel" and "on first click show panel" then "on second click unshow panel" but when you click you still hover the actual button so the hover event is still triggered.

I made a JSfiddle for ya so you can actually see how I solved the problem :
https://jsfiddle.net/Voltra/v7q60217/1/

```
$(".dropdown").on("mouseover",function(){
    console.log('hovering');
  $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").css("display","block");
});

var cl = 0;

$(".dropdown").on("mouseleave",function(){
    console.log('not hovering');
  if(cl!=1){
    $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").css("display","none");
  }
});

$(".dropdown").on("click",function(){
    console.log('toggle')
    $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").toggleClass('openCont');
    cl+=1;
    if(cl == 2){
        cl=0;
        $(this).trigger("mouseleave");
    }
});
```

EDIT:a working version of what's above
https://jsfiddle.net/Voltra/v7q60217/3/

```
$(".dropdown").on("mouseover",function(){
    console.log('hovering');
  $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").css("display","block");
});


$(".dropdown").on("mouseleave",function(){
    console.log('not hovering');
    if($(this).prop('cl')!=1){
      $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").css("display","none");
    }
});

$(".dropdown").on("click",function(){
    if($(this).prop('cl') === undefined){
        $(this).prop('cl',0);
    }
    console.log('toggle');
    $(this).find("div.dropdown-content").toggleClass('openCont');
    $(this).prop('cl',$(this).prop('cl')+1);
    if($(this).prop('cl') == 2){
        $(this).prop('cl',0);
        $(this).trigger("mouseleave");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Vivick, if I open both buttons on click , second click is not closing the content